# Sequelize and client side html

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

i have very little experience with databases and some experience with web development.  I have a web page in which i have html, and typescript (client side) for already.  This is mostly a personal project so i do not plan on making a server side for it.  I am trying to use sequelize to access a database i downloaded.  I have used npm to install sequelize and @types/sequelize.  The @types/sequelize portion works great, as i can see function definitions and what not.  However when i do this:

```
console.log("test");
    const test = new sequelize('database', {
      host: 'localhost',
      operatorsAliases: false,
      storage: "Assets\Database\world_sql_content_41c0c1b4c24be541f595c59b86ef9fb6-1.content"
    });
    console.log(test);
  }
```

i get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
>           at index.js:8
>       http://192.168.1.12:8080/sequelize 404 (Not Found)
>       Uncaught (in promise) Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
>         Instantiating http://192.168.1.12:8080/sequelize
>         Loading http://192.168.1.12:8080/dist/src/sqlFunctions.js
>         Loading app
>           at system.js:4

From what i understand i am not using the correct settings for my project to call module.exports or require (when i try to use require it gives me an error that it is undefined).  I can import just fine however using "import name from source".
Here is my general setup:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es6",                       
    "module": "system",                    
    // "lib": [],                          
    "allowJs": true,                       
    "outDir": "dist",                      
    "rootDir": "./",                       
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                        
    "noImplicitAny": true,                 
    // "strictNullChecks": true,           
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,           
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true
    "noImplicitThis": true,                
    "alwaysStrict": true,                  
    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            
      "esModuleInterop": true              
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "main": "dist/src/ts/main.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.27.31",
    "@types/sqlite3": "^3.1.3",
    "concurrently": "^3.6.1",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "node": "^10.12.0",
    "sequelize": "^4.41.2",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.4",
    "systemjs": "^0.21.5",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

any ideas on how i could fix this or what i might be doing wrong?

also if there are any other resource that might be helpful let me know i will post them.

Thanks everyone!

edit:
this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <title>Sundance Stats</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/Assets/CSS/index.css">
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/sequelize/index.js"></script>
        <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
            <script>
                    System.import('app');
                  </script>
        <div class="Container">
            <div class="Logo">
                <img id="logo" src="./src/Assets/Images/SSLogoV3.png" alt="Logo">

            </div>
            <div class="Line">
                <img id="divLine" src="./src/Assets/Images/divider.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the index.js that the error references

```
'use strict';

/**
  * The entry point.
  *
  * @module Sequelize
  */
module.exports = require('./lib/sequelize');
```

Comment: Post the entire index.js. How are we supposed to know what you have on line 8 there?

Comment: i cannot post it right now, however that is the index.js that is in the sequelize package.  I have not created my own index.js in this project.  I will also post the index.html when i post the other.

Comment: Alright i updated the origonal post to show the error reference file and my own index.html